# How do connect to MySQL on Mac OS X El Capitan just by typing MySQL?

Tags: mysql, macos

How do connect to MySQL on Mac OS X El Captain just by typing MySQL? I made a .bash_proile file in my home directory with:
`export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"`, but when I type mysql in the terminal when I am in my home directory I get this error

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Also how can I list all the users on the server?

Comment: How mysql should now about username and password you want to provide? I'm not sure, but I think it's impossible just with bash profile.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the credentials as command line arguments. From the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html

mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name